# Unity (Object name vs gameobject)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scripting, monodevelop

I'm taking an online class for game development using unity, the instructor can at sometimes be vague. I am under the impression that using gameobject is the same as using the game objects name(in this case it is MusicPlayer), but when I try and replace MusicPlayer instance with gameobject instance, I get the errorCS0246: The type or namespace name `gameobject' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference? I am just trying to understand the difference between the two. Thank you in advance.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
public class MusicPlayer : MonoBehaviour {
static MusicPlayer instance = null;
 void Awake(){
    if (instance != null){
    Destroy(gameObject);
    Debug.Log("Duplicate MusicPlayer Destroyed");
    }

    else{
    instance = this;
    GameObject.DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
    Debug.Log("Original MusicPlayer Created!");
    }
}
}
```

This is the code that I am getting error with:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
public class MusicPlayer : MonoBehaviour {
public static gameobject instance = null;

void Awake(){
    if (instance != null){
    Destroy(gameObject);
    Debug.Log("Duplicate MusicPlayer Destroyed");
    }

    else{
    instance = this;
    GameObject.DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
    Debug.Log("Original MusicPlayer Created!");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: The difference between what? Also add the code you are getting error with.

Comment: The code is there? Am I missing something?

Comment: I understand what you meant now, I want to know why I cannot use gameObject  and must use the name of the gameObject. (shown in line 4 of both codes)

Comment: Well check my answer. It solves your error and shows you why the first code is used instead of the second one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a difference between `gameObject` and `GameObject`. Notice the capitalized "G" in the second one.

[GameObject](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.html) is a class. You can create an instance of it like this:

```
GameObject myobject = new GameObject("PhilipBall");
```

or you can make it a public variable and assign it from the Editor:

```
public  GameObject myobject;
```

---

`gameObject` is a variable that is created from GameObject. It is declared like the `myobject` variable example above.

The reason you can't see it is because it is declared inside a class named `Component`. Then a class called `Behaviour` inherits from that `Component` class. There is another class named `MonoBehaviour` which inherits from the `Behaviour` class. Finally, your script which is called MusicPlayer  inherits from `MonoBehaviour` when you did `public class MusicPlayer : MonoBehaviour`. Because of this you inherit the `gameObject` variable and can use it.

---

The `gameObject` variable type of [GameObject](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.html) class and is used to refer to the GameObject this script is attached to.

> I want to know why I cannot use gameObject and must use the name of
>   the gameObject

You can actually do that. Just replace `public static gameobject instance = null;` with `public static GameObject instance = null;` then `instance = this;` with `instance = this.gameObject;`.

```
public class MusicPlayer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static GameObject instance = null;

    void Awake()
    {
        if (instance != null)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
            Debug.Log("Duplicate MusicPlayer Destroyed");
        }

        else
        {
            instance = this.gameObject;
            GameObject.DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
            Debug.Log("Original MusicPlayer Created!");
        }
    }
}
```

When you use this, you are referring to this script which is `MusicPlayer`. When you use `this.gameObject`, you are referring to this GameObject this script is attached to.

**Why is `public static GameObject instance = null;` not used by your instructor?**

This is because they want to access the `MusicPlayer` script variables, functions during run-time.They don't need the GameObject. Now, this can be done with a GameObject but you will have to perform extra steps such as using `GetComponent` in order to use a variable or call a function in that script.

For example, you have a function named "runFunction" in that script and you want to call it. With the first example, you can just do:

```
MusicPlayer.instance.runFunction();
```

With the second example, you have to do:

```
MusicPlayer.instance.GetComponent<MusicPlayer>().runFunction();
```

That's the big difference and also note that `GetComponent` is expensive.

Comment: Thank you very much, I understand it better now.